# JSON array undefined in Android

Tags: android, json, cordova, in-app-purchase

I use a Phonegap in Android application.

```
ownObject = InAppBilling.prototype.getAvailableProducts(successHandler, errorHandler);
```

ownObject - JSON array of the list of owned products as a parameter. But if i use

```
alert(ownObject);
```

or

```
alert(JSON.stringify(ownObject));
```

it shows me this data as undefined. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using org.json.JSONArray and org.json.JSONObject, I would highly suggest doing so. Your next step would be to surround the block of code with a try and catch block and read what the Logcat has to say.

This will help identify the origin of your problem, as it's impossible to know exactly where you are getting this data from and where it's being passed to.

Instead of:

```
JSON.stringify(object);
```

Try:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
object.put("string_value_1", my_string);

// Or if you have the serialized JSON string...

JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json_string);

// To convert a JSON object to a string...

object.toString();
object.toString(4); // Indicates the spaces to use for indentation
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: No, java code is ok. The main problem is in JS code.

Comment: So now that we've clarified that this is a JavaScript related question, your best bet is to identify if there are any errors in the page. Try taking a look at the JavaScript console (using Safari or Google Chrome). Using the Android tag in the question can mislead people into believing you need help with Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: @ConnerHarkness What I can infer from his single code statement is that he is trying to get the **return value** from an **Asynchronous call** (`ownObject = InAppBilling....getAvailableProducts(successHandler, errorHandler)`) which will **always** return undefined. He needs to handle the return data in the successhandler.